# how do I save an iTextSharp.text.Image to file

Tags: file, save, itext

Im generating a Complex Mail Data Mark image to a PDF, which is fine, and works, using the  iTextSharp.text.pdf.BarcodeDatamatrix, then iTextSharp.text.Image to create the actual image.

However, I want to save this generated image to a file like PNG or jPG.
I have got part way successful, but the pixel size of the image is only 44x44px   I need to to be 300x300px and be good quality, not blurry, because when I blow the size up fro 44x44 to anything greater the quality / clarity of the image suffers.

I have used this so far

```
Dim newImg As System.Drawing.Image = code128.CreateDrawingImage(Drawing.Color.Black, Drawing.Color.White)


dim original As Bitmap = CType(newImg, Bitmap)
dim resized As Bitmap = New Bitmap(original, 100, 100)
resized.Save(Server.MapPath("~/PDFs/" & OrderID & ".jpg"))
```

Which works.. but wow the image is blurry.

I was hoping that someone else has had similar requirements, and had success?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you need the intermediate PDF? If you don't need the PDF, then you can skip that step and generate a Datamatrix barcode directly with ZXing.Net, the .NET port of the ZXing barcode library. I'm pretty sure that a NuGet package is available.

Comment: The PDF needs generating, which is not a prob.  I have seen several QRBarocde / and various other plugins.. but may try ZXing - the ones I have tried so far.. baring in mind I already generate a CMDM barcode - look nooking like the one im generating for RoyalMail in the PDF as their one is a CMDM type 12 or ECC200 - but still the matrix pattern when rendered dont look like the original.  - I will try ZXing though - cheers :)

Comment: I expect that the barcode data generated by iText in PDF, or by ZXing in an image, is the same, because as far as I know it's based on the same code.